# Woocommerce Remove hidden products from WP_Query loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce product that is set to Catalog visibility: Hidden I want to exclude these types of products from my WP_Query. How can I do this? Here is my code which grabs all the products

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this as well:
[usgin pre_get_posts](https://whoischris.com/remove-catalog-visibility-hidden-products-in-woocommerce-from-search-wp-rest-api-results/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using meta query. Kindly check below code for the same.

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
    'key'       => '_visibility',
    'value'     => 'hidden',
    'compare'   => '!=',
      )
    )
   );

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks but that seems to grab none of the products

Answer (score 0):

As of WooCommerce 3 visibility is now a taxonomy not meta. Here's the code for this;

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers don't help me with WooCommerce 5.5.1
If you are use WP_Query (as same as i'd used) only one way will help.
Add this

```
'post_status' => 'publish',
```

All code for $args look's like:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If use wc_get_products, so:

```
$args = array(
  'visibility' => 'visible',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```